# Multiple Data Validation Rules In Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I am trying to write a formula in Excel data validation that meets one or the other condition.

I tried the following, but it does not trigger the validation pop-up box.

The formula is as follows:

```
=OR(SUM($E$11)<=8,SUM($E$11)<4)
```

I have unchecked "Ignore Blanks".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, your formula gives the following results:
[image: test]

These are the results you would expect as they all meet "<=8" except the first one - the second condition never gets evaluated...

However, if you use data validation and set "whole number" and "between "4" and "8" then you may get the results you want, but as i said I am not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi.  I tried to simplify my question and I see I made it more confusing.  It should have been the following: